# Saving lastlogin in a table

Tags: postgresql, function, time

I have the following table in my database, with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users(

owner character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
password character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
createdate timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
lastlogin timestamp without time zone,
CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (owner) );
```

Following Question , is it possible to write a function/stored procedure, that automatically saves and updates the lastlogin value, with the last login from the owner, on this table?

Comment: yes it is possible, you just need to trigger a stored procedure at the time of login. Check documentation if you are using mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Actually I am using postgres 10.5 with pgADMIN 4v3
I can imagine how the trigger Looks like, could you give me an example for the stored procedure, I cant quite imagine.